# Unique elements as a sublist for a number in column 1 from column 2

Tags: pandas, dataframe, loops, unique, series

I have one column (1st column). It has list of numbers. I want unique numbers from column 2 for that specific number in column 1. The columns look like attached image.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 5 | 8 |

I want to get output like [[2],[4],[8]]

Comment: What if the 4 was a 2? What should be the output?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to extract unique values from Column B based on each distinct value in Column A. Here's a basic way to do this in Python using a Pandas DataFrame:

#### Updated

```py
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'Column A': [1, 1, 3, 5], 'Column B': [2, 2, 4, 8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  

result = [list(x) for x in df.groupby('Column A')['Column B'].unique()]
print(result)
```

In this code, the list comprehension `[list(x) for x in ...]` is used to convert each NumPy array to a list. This will give you the desired output `[[2], [4], [8]]`.

Here's a step-by-step explanation:

1. **Import Pandas:**

   - Import the Pandas library.
2. **Create a DataFrame:**

   - Create a Pandas DataFrame with your sample data.
3. **Group by Column A:**

   - Use `groupby` to group the DataFrame by values in Column A.
4. **Extract Unique Values:**

   - For each group, use `unique()` to get unique values from Column B.
5. **Convert to List:**

   - Convert the result to a list.

Note: Make sure to install the Pandas library if you haven't already by running `pip install pandas` in your terminal.

Comment: Many thanks!!!How to  get only list. I dont want dtype and array. I just want list of numbers (list inside the list).

Comment: Updated the answer. Check now @Dr.KrishnaKantGupta

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a list comprehension, Thank you.